# Do lex and yacc provide optimized code?

Tags: yacc, lex

Do Lex and Yacc provide optimized code or is it required that we write our own code manually for higher performance?

Comment: I think the main problem with generated parsers is giving the exact location and cause of syntax errors and not performance. The table-based approach employed by LALR(1)-based parser generation tools is pretty optimal, regarding speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you write has a substantial effect on the speed, especially on the lexer side. Some versions of Flex come with half a dozen (or so) different word counters, most written with Flex, and a few written by hand -- the code gives a pretty good idea of how to optimize scanning speed (and a fairly reasonable comparison of what you can expect in hand-written vs. machine generated lexers).

On the parser side, you're generally a bit more constrained -- you can't make as many changes without affecting the semantics. Here, a great deal depends on the parser generator you use -- for example, some algorithms for less constrained grammars consistently produce relatively slow parsers, while other algorithms only slow down for the less constrained constructs, and run relatively fast as long as the input doesn't use the more complex constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Yacc produces a table-driven parser, which can never be as fast as a well-written hand-coded one. I don't know if the same applies to lex.

Comment: [ *citation needed* ]. How would you design a parser with vastly superior performance to the table approach? As far as I was aware of that *is* a pretty fast method of parsing.

Comment: [Here](http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/journal/1773/abstract?CRETRY=1&SRETRY=0) is the abstract to a paper on generating hard-coded parsers. They claim a 2 to 6 times speed-up over yacc.

Comment: Abstract says: *We have developed a yacc-compatible parser generator that creates parsers that are 2.0 to 6.0 times faster than those generated by yacc or bison. Our tool, mule, creates directly-executable, hard-coded parsers in ANSI; yacc produces interpreted, table-driven parsers.*   HARD coded is not HAND coded.

Comment: I.e. Yacc basically has a table-driven DFA state machine for recognizing the reduction handles. It is not much surprise that this can be turned into code instead. But does this Mule put out parsers comparable to parsers that someone would write by hand? Would someone use the same technique to write similar code that the tool does? In any case, it does establish existence, anyway.

Comment: @Kaz: Hard-coded parsers and hand-coded parsers are likely to be similar. The fact that they are created via different processes is immaterial, especially since the key point is that yacc isn't optimal, not that hand-coded (or hard-coded) is.

Comment: Yes; the work suggests that the table implementation strategy for LARL(1) can be beaten. I.e. the common implementations of the tool do not in fact provide the best possible code.